# How do you conditionally generate a template file via an NX Generator

Tags: nrwl-nx

I've written a custom nx generator that wraps the `@nx/express` generator which allows me to add some project specific customizations to the express app.

It's all working well, but I now have a requirement to generate the **<conditional file>.ts** file, only if a certain condition is true.

```
express-app
│   ...
│
└───src
    │   main.ts
    │   ...
    │
    └───routes
        │   controller.ts
        │   service.ts
        │   <conditional file>.ts
        │   ...
```

Is this possible to achieve using **generateFiles** from `@nx/devkit` or is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You generate the file as you normally would, then in your generator code delete it from the tree.

```
    generateFiles(
        tree,
        path.join(FILES_DIR, 'files'),
        `apps/my-app`,
        params
    );

    if(/** some condition **) {
       tree.delete('apps/my-app/conditional_file.ts');
    }
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. That is what I ended up doing. Sometimes I get so caught up trying to do it in one step I forget I can do it easily in 2 steps.